# Why is my variable not being assigned the correct value when used in ternary context?

Tags: php, variable-assignment, ternary-operator

I'm confused as to why this code:

```
$mapped_class = ( $mapped_field_index = array_search( $field_name, $automapped_header ) !== false ) ? " mapped mapped_to-" . $mapped_field_index : "";
```

... consistently returns `1` as the `$mapped_field_index` (when applicable)

Whereas this, expanded code:

```
$mapped_field_index = array_search( $field_name, $automapped_header );
$mapped_class = $mapped_field_index !== false ? " mapped mapped_to-" . $mapped_field_index : "";
```

... displays the correct search index as the `$mapped_field_index`.

I thought that in PHP an assignment within an IF context is evaluated as an expression as well and returns the assigned value. This seems to hold true in both these examples as the `$mapped_class` is blank in situations where the `array_search()` yields no results.

But I would have expected `$mapped_field_index` to contain the correct `array_search()` index, in both cases, as opposed to just `1` in the ternary form (which seems to indicate TRUE rather than an actual index).

Does the ternary operator have a contributing effect here?

Comment: You probably should use the second example anyway: it's more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparison operators have a higher precedence than assignment.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

(your !== clause is being grouped before your = clause)

Try adding parentheses like this (not 100% sure it will work, but it may)

```
$mapped_class = ( ($mapped_field_index = array_search( $field_name, $automapped_header )) !== false ) ? " mapped mapped_to-" . $mapped_field_index : "";
```

Comment: Yep. I can't believe I made such a rookie mistake. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

`$mapped_field_index` isn't being set to the same value in the two cases. In the first example, `$mapped_field_index` is equal to the result of

`array_search( $field_name, $automapped_header ) !== false`

In the second example, it's equivalent to

`array_search( $field_name, $automapped_header )`

If you modify the second example so the first line reads:

`$mapped_field_index = array_search( $field_name, $automapped_header ) !== false;`

then you'll always get 1 in that case too.

In a case like this where there's no efficiency difference, you're better off with wordier, but more readable syntax anyway.

Comment: You're probably right that clear is better than clever here. Especially since clever gets you caught...

Comment: Clear is better than clever: I will use (steal) that one! Thanks!